# Most efficient way of getting a Vector.<int> from SQLite into AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, vector

I've got a LOT of vertex coords stored in a SQLite db.

I'm using Away3D 4, so I can directly set these coords into the model geometry by passing them as a Vector.<int>

Now, I need to optimize badly, because it's very time consuming atm. I store the ints as JSON in SQLite and convert them to Vector.<int> at runtime.

Is there a faster way? Can I store the Vector.<int> as a byteArray maybe? Or as an AS3 object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do you're processing on the server rather than the client it will speed things up. Using [AMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format) rather than JSON would allow you to send binary data (serialized AS3 objects) over the wire. There are AMF implementations for the most popular server-side languages; Java, .NET, PHP, Ruby, and Python (even Erlang).

AMF deserialization is built into the Flash player so it will run orders of magnitude faster than parsing JSON strings.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Said SQLiteDB is stored locally though. Still use AMF?

Comment: Is the data to be saved larger than 100kb? If not you could use local storage which uses AMF http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2009/06/23/flash-sol/ or if it is > 100kb then something along these lines might work http://killerspaz.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/flex-serialization/